# Removing the colon from the \ref command with \label in latex

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, packages

[image]I'm writing my thesis using overleaf editor and I have some tables. When I \ref them I had colon in the default name. How can I remove this colons?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post images of code. Instead please post the code as text to your answer.

Comment: that is not the default behaviour, so you have to undo whatever you have done to add the colon.

Comment: by default `\ref` would just make 2.1 you have changed that, perhaps by redefining `\thetable` but we can not debug an image. Make a smal complete example